# Generate RSA Key with PKCS11

Tags: java, rsa, pkcs#11, iaik-jce

I am trying to generate an RSA-2048 key with my HSM, using PKCS11 standard, It seems to be ok for the private key, but when I try to wrap my public key I get this error :
iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_KEY_HANDLE_INVALID

Here is the generation function:

```
    public long [] Generate_RSA_key() {
             long [] key = null;
             try {
                 CK_MECHANISM mec = new CK_MECHANISM();
                 mec.mechanism = PKCS11Constants.CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN;
                 
                 RSAPublicKey  pub_template = new RSAPublicKey();
                 RSAPrivateKey prv_template = new RSAPrivateKey();
                 
                 RSA_template(pub_template, prv_template);
                 
                 CK_ATTRIBUTE[] attr_pub = iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.objects.Object.getSetAttributes(pub_template);
                 CK_ATTRIBUTE[] attr_prv = iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.objects.Object.getSetAttributes(prv_template);
                 
                 
                 key = cryptoki.C_GenerateKeyPair(ckiSession, mec, attr_pub, attr_prv, true);
             }catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return key;        
    }

     private void RSA_template(RSAPublicKey pub_template, RSAPrivateKey prv_template) {
         pub_template.getEncrypt()      .setBooleanValue(TRUE);
         pub_template.getVerify()       .setBooleanValue(TRUE);
         pub_template.getWrap()         .setBooleanValue(TRUE);
         pub_template.getModulusBits()  .setLongValue(2048L);
         
         prv_template.getDecrypt()      .setBooleanValue(TRUE);
         prv_template.getSign()         .setBooleanValue(TRUE);
         prv_template.getExtractable()  .setBooleanValue(TRUE);
         prv_template.getModulusBits()  .setLongValue(2048L);
         
     }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to generate a keypair _in_ the HSM, or to import the keypair generated in software? Those are totally different things, and neither of them uses C_GenerateKey.

Comment: a *tiny* typo in (last line of) `RSA_Template()`method!? ;) (`pub_`-> `prv_`)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I am trying to generate a keypair in the hsm, I am trying to use C_GenerateKeyPair

Comment: @xerx593 Thank you ! I have changed that :)

Comment: oh, only in the post!? i hoped it could/would solve the issue :)

Comment: @xerx593 unfortunately that did not solve the problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do by wrapping the public key? Are you trying to extract it?